# What is the best way to achieve database synchronization?

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, wordpress, database-design

I am looking to build software that has an Iphone application as well as a Wordpress based website.  Essentially the user will enter data into the iphone app that will then be relayed to the Wordpress site and displayed in various manners.

Whats the best way to get the iphone database and CMS database to communicate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might go without saying, but generally speaking I would try to keep your client (iPhone) app as 'dumb' as possible; Your Wordpress DB should really own all of the content, and the data stored on the iPhone should be as temporal as possible. To put it another way, your app should be like a WP theme.  A theme doesn't really 'know' about the WP database - it's just responsible for displaying it (and occasionally adding to it with things like comment forms).

Anyway, as for the actual communication I would recommend keeping as much in JSON as possible (I've found it easier than XML). There's a great plug-in for Wordpress that can help you out, that exposes WP functionality in a JSON-based API: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

As for working with JSON on the phone itself, I highly recommend the json-framework: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/ . In short, it'll convert a JSON string into an NSDictionary in one method. Incredibly useful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too obvious, but usually for database communicaton used XML, CSV, JSON etc.